# Scroll text over windows media player c#

Tags: c#, video-processing

I took a windowsMediaPlayer control. How can I set scroll text?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "(mp4,mov,wmv,mpg)|*.mp4;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpg|all files|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            //How can I set my scrolling text
            //axWindowsMediaPlayer1.ScrollText = "It is my demo text";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I take a WindowsMediaPlayer control & play video by setting axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your talking about the windows built-in media player then your going to have to get down and dirty with the Win32 API's, windows hooks, HWND, etc. You can't just paint a control on the window. What your talking about is some very low level windows coding.

Take a look at Spy++ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx). It's a tool from Microsoft that let's you delve into the details of a running application. It has a component called ManagedSpyLib which wraps the C++ windows libraries in a managed library to make the windows hooks calls easier. Be ready to learn more about the OS than you ever wanted to know. :-)